# Querying in mongodb 3.4

Tags: mongodb

I have large XML files which I had to convert in json and store in mongodb. The python code for conversion and insertion is:

```
import pymysql
import re
import json
import xmltodict
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Open Database Connection.
db = pymysql.connect("fffff","ddd","fgf","hnj")

# prepare a cursor object
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL query 
cursor.execute("SELECT jlp.appid, convert(MAX(lex.response) using utf8) FROM jos_lender_portfolio jlp INNER JOIN jos_lexnex_data lex ON jlp.appid = lex.appid\
                group by appid limit 10;")

# Fetch all rows
data = cursor.fetchall()

a = (r'(?=<response>)(.*)(?<=</response>)')
def cleanxml(xml):
    if re.findall(a, xml, re.S):
        file = re.findall(a, xml, re.S)[0]
    else:
        file = "<response>NA</response>"
    return file
data = list(data)
client = MongoClient()
db = client['lexnex']
collection = db['test']
for row in data:
    thexml = cleanxml(row[1])
    jsonString = json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(thexml), indent = 4)
    d = json.loads(jsonString)
    newdict = {"caseid" : row[0]}
    newdict.update(d)
    jsondata = json.dumps(newdict, indent = 3)
    f = json.loads(jsondata)
    db.test.insert_one(f)
```

Now, the problem: I'm very new to mongodb and having problem in querying my database.I have the following json:

```
"_id":ObjectId("5aeff8537871560bf05d8c25"),
"caseid":44136,
"response":{
   "Header":{
      "TransactionId":"18092257R1069402",
      "Status":"0"
   },
   "Records":{
      "Record":[
         {
            "Filings":{
               "Filing":{
                  "Type":"INITIAL FILING",
                  "Date":{
                     "Day":"23",
                     "Month":"9",
                     "Year":"2008"
                  }
               }
            },
            "FilingJurisdiction":"NY",
            "MatchedParty":{
               "PartyType":"D",
               "Address":{

                  "City":"BROOKLYN",
                  "State":"NY",
                     },
               "OriginName":"GOLDLINE"
            },
            "Secureds":{
               "Secured":{
                  "Addresses":{
                     "Address":{
                        "City":"SCHAUMBURG",
                        "State":"IL"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         {
,
            "Filings":{
               "Filing":{
                  "Type":"INITIAL FILING",
                  "Date":{
                     "Day":"23",
                     "Month":"9",
                     "Year":"2008"
                  }
               }
            },
            "FilingJurisdiction":"NY",
            "MatchedParty":{
               "PartyType":"D",
               "Address":{
                  "City":"BROOKLYN",
                  "State":"NY",
               },
               "OriginName":"GOLD"
            },
            "Secureds":{
               "Secured":{
                  "Addresses":{
                     "Address":{
                        "City":"SCHAUMBURG",
                        "State":"IL"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This is a small portion of a very big document and there are more than a million such documents. Now, the expected result which I want is for every `caseid`, some part of the `Filings` and the `Secureds`. Here's the sample expected output:

```
"_id":ObjectId("5aeff8537871560bf05d8c25"),
"caseid":44136,
"Filings":{
   [
      "Filing":{
         "Type":"INITIAL FILING",
         "Date":{
            "Day":"23",
            "Month":"9",
            "Year":"2008"
         }
      },
      "Secureds":{
         "Secured":{
            "Addresses":{
               "Address":{
                  "City":"SCHAUMBURG",
                  "State":"IL"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "Filing":{
            "Type":"INITIAL FILING",
            "Date":{
               "Day":"23",
               "Month":"9",
               "Year":"2008"
            }
         }
      },
      "Secureds":{
         "Secured":{
            "Addresses":{
               "Address":{
                  "City":"SCHAUMBURG",
                  "State":"IL"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

There are several caseids and each one has 0 or more filings. I have no clue how to do it. I know the basics like simple queries. But this, I think, requires $unwind and $group together. What I have written so far is nothing but just this:

```
db.test.aggregate([{$unwind:{path: '$response'}},{"$group":{_id:{caseid:"$caseid"}}}])
```

Please help.

Comment: This JSON looks like it was from a direct XML conversion. Is that actually the case? How much control do you have over actually changing this? Because it would be far more productive to change the structure to what you need rather than learning how to query it as it is. There are honestly so many structural problems here that it would be far more productive to fix the process which is importing the data instead.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. This is a parsed XML converted to json and inserted in mongodb. I have full control over it. I can structure it whatever way I want..but I don't know how to do it. The thing is that it is a big json. This is just the relevant part of it. Is there a way I can pass one file to you...maybe that will help better in solving the problem.

Comment: Can we change the context of the question then before anyone tries to answer? And then include the XML conversion. That's probably going to be a better question. I presume it's mostly the detail of each `Filings` entry which is the important part you need to query. Also state if you really need it in one document under the "caseid" or if it can happily be split into different documents for each `Filings` with "caseid" in combination.

Comment: I can post the python code which I used to convert the xml. The thing is that I will have to parse the entire xml. I can't parse only the required parts. This is the present requirement. If later something else comes up, I will have to query that. We can split it into several documents but the preference is caseid wise. Like, if you are familiar with SQL, we just group by caseid.

Comment: That's okay. If you're only parsing certain "chunks" from between certain tag paths then that's not an issue. What really needs to happen is cleaning up the "very XMLish" naming and structure into something better suited for a "database".

Comment: How would you know unless you have the XML or the converted json? How do we change the xmlish naming convention to something better for so big and large no. of documents?

Comment: Because if it's coded in python, then what is actually happening is `XML -> Python List/Dicts` and then `Python List/Dicts -> MongoDB` since the driver will then just do the conversion. So the "alteration" is better happening at the `Python List/Dicts` stage before it even gets persisted to the database.

Comment: I have posted the code as well. So, you are saying that before inserting into mongo I should restructure the entire converted json. The hierarchy is very deep, it will be time consuming to do that.